# Font size is bold with PhantomJs screenshot

Tags: fonts, phantomjs, screenshot

I use rasterize.js to create a pdf. The PDF is a capture of web page.

However, the text of PDF is more fat of web page. Therefore, the formatting is not correct.

I have installed PhantomJS 1.9 on Debian 7 with freetype and fontconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be installed ttf-mscorefonts-installer package on Debian.

For more informations : http://installion.co.uk/debian/wheezy/contrib/t/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/en/install/index.html